# Using an enum value to represent two enum values

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Picture the scene.

```
public enum SaveStates
{
    Saved,               //Represents a successful save.
    SavedWithChanges,    //Represents a successful save, where records were modified
    SavedWithoutChanges  //Represents a successful save, but no records were modified
}
```

In this scenario, the enumeration can be considered `Saved` if it's `SavedWithChanges` **or** `SavedWithoutChanges`.

So if I were to have a variable like this:

```
SaveStates lastState = SaveStates.SavedWithoutChanges;
```

I'd ideally like to do something like this:

```
if (lastState == SaveStates.Saved)
{
    //The state is saved, do something awesome.
}
```

I can of course do this:

```
if (lastState == SaveStates.SavedWithChanges || lastState == SaveStates.SavedWithoutChanges)
{
    ...
```

However this is a bit tedious and I can't assume that another developer is going to understand how to correctly use the enumeration.

Each enumeration is required as there may be an instance where we might want to do something specific in the event of a save where there has been no changes for example.

I'm open to alternative design ideas.

Comment: I don't think that  another developer won't understand that. Imo this is clearer than using flags attribute .

Comment: Shouldn't you have an unsaved value for you enum?  Otherwise why check it to see if it is saved, you'd just use `Enum.IsDefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what worries you is code readability, you can use a little extension method like this:

```
public static class SaveStatesExtension
{
    public static bool IsSavedState(this SaveStates state) {
        return state == SaveStates.SavedWithChanges || 
               state == SaveStates.SavedWithoutChanges;
    }
}
```

Then your usage example becomes:

```
if (lastState.IsSavedState())
{
    //The state is saved, do something awesome.
}
```

Of course the `Saved` member in the enum is no longer needed in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this as follows, going by the example of the link I've posted under the question but using non-exclusive flag values. Note that both `SavedWithChanges` and `SavedWithoutChanges` contain the bit `1`, assigned to `Saved`.

```
[Flags]
public enum SaveStates
{
    Saved = 1,
    SavedWithChanges = 3,
    SavedWithoutChanges = 5
}

if ((lastState & SaveStates.Saved) == SaveStates.Saved)
{

}
```

However, this can be rather unintuitive to other developers - usually flag enums are not used this way. So explicitly stating all conditions with all enum values might be much more readable. Very good idea [posted by Konamiman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33147453/2642204):

```
public static bool IsSaved(SaveStates state)
{
    return state == SaveStates.SavedWithChanges
        || state == SaveStates.SavedWithoutChanges;
}
```

combines best of two worlds: [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) satisfied while being concise and readable.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to do it with a `Flags` enum, you should make it self-documenting

```
[Flags]
public enum SaveStates
{
    Saved = 1,
    WithChanges = 2,
    SavedWithoutChanges = Saved, // a bit pointless! Its the same as Saved
    SavedWithChanges = Saved | WithChanges  // has value "3"
}
```

And then, as per other answers

```
if ((lastState & SaveStates.Saved) == SaveStates.Saved)
{

}
```

Comment: Is it me or are you doing these flags completely wrong. When using flags you should use all components. And do `Saved` as `Saved = With | Without`

Comment: Upvoting this answer. For me, it's more intuitive that whether something was "Saved" and "Was Changed" are two different things. Putting them into one enum causes part of the confusion. I would probably take it a step further and have a property for both Save state and Change state. Why do I think this? What will you do when you save something with changes, then make a change and save it again? You have to evaluate whether prior changes have been made when determining the new enum to select. Everything else can be wrapped up into extension methods to set/get these values as needed.

Comment: @kevintjuh93 - it's you ;)

Comment: @Jamiec but seriously... `Saved` is both `with and without` changes. So it should be the other way around.

Comment: @kevintjuh93 whether this is a good scheme is up to the OP, I agree it may not be the best way to represent the saved state of something. This answer was an attempt to show that, while its possible to do with a `Flags` enum (as per the answers that came before mine) there is a way to do it the same way, but to add some level of self-documentation to the code.

Answer (score 1):

What about changing your enumeration?

```
public enum SaveStates
{
    NotSaved,               //Represents "not saved" state
    SavedWithChanges,    //Represents a successful save, where records were modified
    SavedWithoutChanges  //Represents a successful save, but no records were modified
}
```

In this case you can use negation for the purpose you're speaking of:

```
if (lastState != SaveStates.NotSaved)
{
    //The state is saved, do something awesome.
}
```

Also, it gives you an enumeration value which can be used as the "default" one which is considered a good, "clean code" practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer this:

```
SaveStates[] savedWithOrWithoutChanges = { SaveStates.SavedWithChanges, SaveStates.SavedWithoutChanges };
if (savedWithOrWithoutChanges.Contains(lastStat))
{
    ...
}
```

This is very intuitive, every developer will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of one enum to represent two things why not just use two `bool` values.  One to indicate if it is saved and the other to indicate if it is "with changes".  Then you'd just ignore the second if the first is false.

```
private bool saved;

private bool withChanges;

public void SomeMethod()
{
    if (saved)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Saved");

        if (withChanges)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("With Changes");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Without Changes");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not saved");
    }
}
```